# use SQL in DStream.transform() over Spark Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

There are some examples for use SQL over Spark Streaming in `foreachRDD()`. But if I want to use SQL in `tranform()`:

```
case class AlertMsg(host:String, count:Int, sum:Double)
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 8888)
lines.transform( rdd => {
  if (rdd.count > 0) {
    val t = sqc.jsonRDD(rdd)
    t.registerTempTable("logstash")
    val sqlreport = sqc.sql("SELECT host, COUNT(host) AS host_c, AVG(lineno) AS line_a FROM logstash WHERE path = '/var/log/system.log' AND lineno > 70 GROUP BY host ORDER BY host_c DESC LIMIT 100")
    sqlreport.map(r => AlertMsg(r(0).toString,r(1).toString.toInt,r(2).toString.toDouble))
  } else {
    rdd
  }
}).print()
```

I got such error:

> [error] /Users/raochenlin/Downloads/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/logstash/src/main/scala/LogStash.scala:52: no type parameters for method transform: (transformFunc: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] => org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U])(implicit evidence$5: scala.reflect.ClassTag[U])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[U] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] => org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_ >: LogStash.AlertMsg with String <: java.io.Serializable])
>   [error]  --- because ---
>   [error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
>   [error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] => org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_ >: LogStash.AlertMsg with String <: java.io.Serializable]
>   [error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] => org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[?U]
>   [error]     lines.transform( rdd => {
>   [error]           ^
>   [error] one error found
>   [error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed

Seems only if I use `sqlreport.map(r => r.toString)` can be a correct usage?

Answer (score 0):

`dstream.transform` take a function `transformFunc: (RDD[T]) ⇒ RDD[U]`
In this case, the `if` must result in the same type on both evaluations of the condition, which is not the case:

```
if (count == 0) => RDD[String]
if (count > 0) => RDD[AlertMsg]
```

In this case, remove the optimization of `if rdd.count ...` sothat you have an unique transformation path.